# How can I wrap text from the indentation level rather than the beginning of the line

Tags: wrapping

This is better shown than explained. The first image shows how line wrapping works in VScode, and the second in vim.

[image: VScode]
[image: vim]

In VScode the wrapped line continues at the indentation level of the line, rather than at the beginning of the document, however this is not the case in vim. For some tasks, the VScode way of wrapping is much cleaner.

Is there any way to get this functionality in vim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, see `:h breakindent`:

```
'breakindent' 'bri' boolean (default off)
            local to window
            {not available when compiled without the |+linebreak|
            feature}
    Every wrapped line will continue visually indented (same amount of
    space as the beginning of that line), thus preserving horizontal blocks
    of text.
```

And also `:h breakindentopt`. I use `set breakindentopt=sbr` and it places `showbreak` symbol to first column.

[image]

For list items it wouldn't indent wrapped lines to be under the text, though. And actually, your vscode example does the same.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. The list items was just an example, i actually prefer the more general functionality